# Isavailable is not a member of QSound

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, qt5

I want to compile some old QT project with QT 5.2.1 and have many trouble, one of which is QSound problem:

```
if(!QSound::isAvailable()) {
    ui.grpSounds->setEnabled(false);
    ui.grpSounds->setTitle(tr("Sounds (Not Available)"));
}
```

error:
 'isAvailable' is not a member of 'QSound'

will anyone help me? I am completely newbie with Qt.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to notify the user whether or not sounds can be played then your best bet is [QAudioDeviceInfo](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtmultimedia/qaudiodeviceinfo.html#availableDevices). You can query for available input or output devices using the static method

```
QList<QAudioDeviceInfo> QAudioDeviceInfo::availableDevices(QAudio::Mode mode)
```

For instance you can replace `QSound::isAvailable()` by

```
!QAudioDeviceInfo::availableDevices(QAudio::AudioOutput).isEmpty()
```

**Edit:**

`QSound` was part of the gui module, but now is part of the multimedia module (which make more sense). You need take a look at the [changes in multimedia modules from Qt4 to Qt5](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtmultimedia/changes.html) for more info. You may also want to look at `QSoundEffect`, which seems to have a richer API

Comment: Thank you very much! ^^ It's works...
I really appreciate your help sir

If you want to help me with similar Qt4 to Qt5 problem I'll wait at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22294737/type-has-not-been-declared
:)

Answer (score 0):

According to class reference, Qt 5.2 don't have Sound::isAvailable() static method http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qsound.html

It was in Qt4.8

Comment: Thank you..
Can you tell me alternative to this function?